# DWB local planner footprint configuration

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I have some issues while trying to use DWB local planner.
I'm using it with move_base using [this answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/312524/how-to-use-the-dwb-local-planner/?answer=312527#post-id-312527).

But when I start the navigation, I get these errors:

```
[ WARN] [1464825005.450915057]: Critic "ObstacleFootprint" failed to prepare
[ERROR] [1464825005.457386149]: computeVelocityCommands exception: No valid trajectories out of 63! 
[ERROR] [1464825005.550973984]: Footprint spec is empty, maybe missing call to setFootprint?
```

I've tried to add in my "base_local_planner_params.yaml" file the "ObstacleFootprint" parameter :

```
  critics:
     ObstacleFootprint: [[-0.3, 0.45], [0.97, 0.45], [0.97, -0.45], [-0.3,-0.45]]
```

But now, my robot goes around in circles with no errors instead of moving towards the destination...

Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313386/dwb-local-planner-footprint-configuration/) by [Dakow](https://answers.ros.org/users/39610/dakow/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2019-01-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

DWB searches for the footprint [here](https://github.com/locusrobotics/robot_navigation/blob/master/nav_2d_utils/src/footprint.cpp#L46)

You'll want to set the `footprint` parameter somewhere in your namespace. Right now, I'm guessing you have the parameter `/move_base/DWBLocalPlanner/critics/ObstacleFootprint` set to the footprint above. What you want is for the footprint to be set anywhere in those namespaces, including

- `/footprint`
- `/move_base/footprint`
- `/move_base/DWBLocalPlanner/footprint`
- `/move_base/DWBLocalPlanner/critics/footprint`
- `/move_base/DWBLocalPlanner/critics/ObstacleFootprint/footprint`

`/move_base/footprint` is traditional, since it allows anything in `move_base` to use the same footprint.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2019-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dakow](https://answers.ros.org/users/39610/dakow/) on 2019-01-23**:
I had it there:

```
/move_base/global_costmap/footprint
/move_base/local_costmap/footprint
```

So I added it too in:

```
/move_base/footprint
```

And it works... Thanks a lot!

**Comment by [liambroek](https://answers.ros.org/users/68649/liambroek/) on 2021-03-18**:
I'm quite new to this, could you explain how exactly you did this? I have the same error.